# Python: разбить список на список списков, по элементу-разделителю

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Python 3.2.

Есть список `lst`, в котором есть значения вперемешку с элементами-разделителями. Например, `["spam", "ham", None, "eggs", None, None, "bacon"]`. Хочу получить список списков, разбив `lst` по разделителю `sep = None`, т.е., получить `[["spam", "ham"], ["eggs"], ["bacon"]]`.

Полистал стандартную библиотеку, но ничего похожего не нашел. На PyPi искать сложно, быстрый пробег тоже ничего не дал. Наглая попытка проэксплуатировать `str.split`, разумеется, провалилась с `TypeError`.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, более красивое решение, чем вот этот вырвиглазный монстр. Не хочу ощущать себя Франкенштейном.

```
from functools import reduce

# Fugly.
def split_on(sep, lst):
    """
    Given an iterable `lst`, split it into iterable of lists by `sep`.

    >>> list(split_on(0, [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6]))
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
    """
    s = sep if hasattr(sep, "__call__") else lambda x: x == sep
    return filter(lambda sublist: len(sublist) > 0,
                  reduce(lambda x, elem: x + [[]] if elem == sep
                                                else x[:-1] + [x[-1] + [elem]],
                         lst, [[]]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- *Судя по всему, функциональное программирование оставило на вас серьезный отпечаток :)*

> Сразу отмечу, что семантика **split** для случая вашего примера подразумевает возврат `[["spam", "ham"], ["eggs"], [], ["bacon"]].` Это так, поскольку между `None` и `None` с точки зрения разделителей располагается пустой список.

- Так вот, решений можно придумать несколько. Наиболее `explicit` вариант подразумевает что-то в следующем духе:

  ```
  def split_on(what, delimiter = None):
      splitted = [[]]
      for item in what:
          if item == delimiter:
              splitted.append([])
          else:
              splitted[-1].append(item)

      return splitted
  ```
- Понятно, что это решение работает с точностью до контракта функции касательно работы в случае пустого списка - `[]` и списка, состоящего *только из разделителя* - `[None].`

> - Я определил этот контракт следующим образом: `[ ] -> [[ ]]`, `[None] -> [[], []]`. **Для первого случая контракт довольно спорный.** Во втором же случае результат получается, поскольку слева и справа от разделителя по сути расположены пустые последовательности.
> - В случае, если вы захотите изменить это поведение, то модифицировать метод не должно составить особого труда.

- *Пример использования:*

  ```
  list1 = ["spam", "ham", None, "eggs", None, None, "bacon"]
  list2 = []
  list3 = [None]
  list4 = ["eggs"]

  print split_on(list1)
  print split_on(list2)
  print split_on(list3)
  print split_on(list4)

  # Результат:
  [['spam', 'ham'], ['eggs'], [], ['bacon']]
  [[]]
  [[], []]
  [['eggs']]
  ```
- Из альтернативных вариантов - можно написать аналогичный предложенной функции генератор с `yield'ами` и, думаю, что можно придумать решение, разбивая предложенную итерабельную последовательность на группы, а дальше объединяя результаты путем `groupby` из `itertools`. *Правда, мне кажется, что очевидность этих решений по сравнению с предложенным выше методом будет несколько хуже.*

Comment: О, вот `groupby`-то я и не заметил. Пожалуй, он мне нравится больше всего в моем конкретном случае, `(part for is_sep, part in groupby(lst, f) if not is_sep)` кажется вполне читаемым.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: @drdaeman Читаемость кода на `python'e` - это тот еще холивар. Хотя, видимо, ваше решение больше попадает под определение `pythonic`, нежели мое.

Comment: @drdaeman Чтобы получить вложенный список списков: `[list(group) for sep, group in groupby(input_list, lambda x: x is None) if not sep]`

Answer (score -1):

```
m=["spam","ham","N","edg","N","N","back"]
q=0
i=0
t=list(([],)*m.count("N"))
for x in m:
    if x=="N":
        q=1
        continue
    if q==1:
        i=i+1
        t[i]=[]
    t[i].append(x)
    print(i,"---",t[i])
    z=input()
=============================
0 --- ['spam']

0 --- ['spam', 'ham']

1 --- ['edg']

2 --- ['back']
t=[['spam', 'ham'], ['edg'], ['back']]
```